# find the most similar value between two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I have two sorted vectors and I want to find the index of a value in vector1 that has the smallest difference (distance) to another value in vector2. My following code does the job, however, because the vectors I use are always sorted I feel there most be another more efficient way to do the same thing. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<limits>
std::vector<float> v1{2,3,6,7,9};
std::vector<float> v2{4,6.2,10};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{    
    float mn=std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    float difference;
    int index;
    for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<v2.size(); j++){
            difference = abs(v1[i]-v2[j]);
            if(difference < mn){
                mn= difference;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<< index; 
    // 2 is the wanted index because |6-6.2| is the smallest distance between the 2 vectors 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is a faster way. You only need to compare elements in v1 to those in v2 that are smaller or equal, or the first that is greater. Basically, the idea is to have two iterators, `i` and `j`, and advance `j` if `v2[j] < v1[i]`, otherwise advance `i`. Here is a possible implementation:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
    while (true) {
        difference = std::abs(v1[i] - v2[j]);
        if (difference < mn) {
            mn = difference;
            index = i;
        }

        // Try the next item in v1 if the current item in v2 is bigger.
        if (v2[j] > v1[i])
              break;

        // Otherwise, try the next item in v2, unless we are at the last item.
        if (j + 1 < v2.size())
                j++;
        else
                break;
    }
}
```

While it still looks like a double loop, it only computes differences at most `v1.size() + v2.size()` times, instead of `v1.size() * v2.size()` times.

Comment: A single loop with `if (v2[j] > v1[i]) i++; else j++;` (which more closely resembles your description of the basic idea, with some code to cater for the ends of the arrays) would be much easier to understand IMO.

Comment: It's not as simple as that, as you also need to check that you don't run out of bounds. But you are right, it could be rewritten with only one loop statement.